# Adicionar e Remover classe de um elemento com scroll - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando fazer com que o navbar tenha uma classe “fixed-top” quando mexer no scroll e remover a classe quando estiver no topo da pagina.

Escrevi o script abaixo mais não esta funcionando.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cb-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    () => {
      let nav = document.getElementById('#nav');
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (window.scrollY > 1.5) {
            nav.classList.add("fixed-top");
            document.body.style.paddingTop = '70';
        }else {
          nav.classList.remove("fixed-top");
          document.body.style.paddingTop = '0';
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o @HostListener para ouvir o evento de scroll.
Você pode usar o ViewChild para pegar a referência do componente e ElementRef para pegar a referência do template que vai mudar também.

Fiz esse exemplo no stackblitz como exemplo.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viewchild-elementref?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Olha o código como ficou

```js
import { Component, HostListener, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private app: ElementRef) {   
  }

  @ViewChild('exemplo', {read: ElementRef}) exemplo:ElementRef;

  @HostListener('window:scroll') onWindowScroll() {
    if (window.scrollY > 1.5) {
      this.exemplo.nativeElement.classList.add("fixed-top");
      this.app.nativeElement.classList.add("padding-top");
    } else {
      this.exemplo.nativeElement.classList.remove("fixed-top");
      this.app.nativeElement.classList.remove("padding-top");
    }    
  }
```

```css
.app {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 5em;
  transition: .3s all;
}

.app.padding-top {
  padding: 15em 3em 3em;
}

.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2em 0;
  transition: .3s all;
}

.fixed-top > h1 {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<my-app class="app">loading</my-app>
<hello #exemplo name="{{ name }}"></hello>
```

Comment: Eu tinha consegui resolver de uma maneira que acredito que não é a correta em angular. Escrevi o código direto no AfterContentIni do componente. O código ficou assim: (() => {
      const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (window.scrollY > 1.5) {
          nav.classList.add("fixed-top");
          document.body.style.paddingTop = "90px";
        } else {
          nav.classList.remove("fixed-top");
          document.body.style.paddingTop = "0px";
        }
      });
    })()
  }

Comment: Assim você esta mexendo direto no DOM, com ElementRef e ViewChild você acessa a referencia do componente e o template.